# how to achieve inline block on top/bottom left or top/bottom right on position relative or anywhere?

Tags: html, css, sass

I have been trying to assign buttons inside a position relative container but when I do position absolute on buttons they are overlapping. I want to position my buttons on top/bottom right or top/bottom left of the square on inline-block, or position them anywhere? what position should I use or how can I achieve? since It's the buttons for social network.By the way I am trying to get a certificate from freecodecamp and I am on course of random quote generator. This is my code:

HTML

```
</div>

<div class="buttons">

<button class="button" id="twitter-button"><a   title="Tweet this quote!" target="_blank"> tweet
  <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
</a></button>

<button class="button" id="facebook-button"><a   title="Share this quote!" target="_blank">share
  <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
</a></button>

</div>

</div>
```

SCSS

```
.quote-box {
text-align: center;
position: relative;
border-radius: 4.5px;
border: solid black 1px;
display: table;
width: 50%;
height: 500px;
padding: 10%;
margin: 10% auto auto auto; /* center the box */
}
.quote-box .buttons .button#twitter-button, .quote-box .buttons    .button#facebook-button {
top: 0;
left:0;
position:absolute;/* out of the document flow and you can move*/
float: left;
margin: 1%;
padding: 1%;
display: inline-block;
}
```

JsFiddle [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iamglenbacs/jazxepve/)

So how do I position or design my buttons inside the positioned relative box? Should I just position theme absolute one by one? I think it's unprofessional and I want to look at my code at its best? i used z-index on them but they are still overlapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a container called "Buttons", make this absolute, and leave your button elements with default position. Also, if you have class "button", you don't need to make 2 secuences like #twitter.button, #facebook.twitter.
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d83j9c4L/4/)

```
.buttons{
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: so how can I move each If I want to position them on other side? sorry I am new

Comment: I've just updated fiddle for you. There are many ways to do it.

float, margin-left, translateX(), position: relative

Even making .buttons div a flexbox and giving #facebook-button a margin-left: auto.

--Change /4/ for /5/ in fiddle URL to see it with display:flex

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `position:absolute` and use float for the buttons.

the CSS

button {float:left;}

Also, z-index determines which elements show on-top of others. So in this case z-index would choose which button to show on top of the other.

Answer (score 1):

You have your buttons inside the div with class "buttons", but that div doesn't have any height or width because the buttons have absolute position.

Therefore, each button is placed relative to the "buttons" div at (0,0).

Move the buttons out of the container or give the container some width and height.

Comment: how can I move each button one by one?maybe a sample fiddle would be more clear to me